# org.hibernate.TransactionException in simple CRUD app with CockroachDB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, kotlin, cockroachdb

The following minimal CRUD example using Spring Boot, Hibernate, JpaRepository, CockroachDB and Kotlin produces `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException` / `org.hibernate.TransactionException`.

The Entity `Thing` in question has just two fields:

```
@Entity
data class Thing (
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    var value: String
)
```

To keep this post short, I stored the actual souce files in gists:

[`./src/main/kotlin/ThingService.kt`](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/5a3c31b89f84aee8b7ee77af6ffbf3e8)

[`./src/main/resources/application.properties`](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/ccb0767bf1cc8f6cebe68fab56831dc2)

[`./build.gradle.kts`](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/34b45de7288a4ad09275bcf5e5be3517)

[`./stress_test.py`](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/187354a457bd8f742869b0294411ae55)

With these files, the issue can be reproduced (on Ubuntu 16.04 in my case) using the following commands.

Download and initialize CockroachDB:

```
# download
wget -qO- https://binaries.cockroachdb.com/cockroach-v1.1.5.linux-amd64.tgz | tar xvz

# start
./cockroach-v1.1.5.linux-amd64/cockroach start --insecure
# leave terminal open in background

# init
cockroach sql --insecure -e "CREATE USER root WITH PASSWORD '123';"
cockroach sql --insecure -e "CREATE DATABASE things_db;"
cockroach sql --insecure -e "GRANT ALL ON DATABASE things_db TO root;"
```

Run data service:

```
gradle bootRun
# leave terminal open in background
```

Run stress test:

```
python3 stress_test.py
```

`stress_test.py` concurrently sends `PUT` requests and `GET` requests (find thing by value) to the service. Most requests work fine, but in between the output looks as follows:

```
PUT OK
find OK
PUT OK
find OK
find OK
find OK
PUT ERROR: {"timestamp":"2018-03-17T16:00:24.616+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection","path":"/thing/"}
find OK
PUT OK
```

[Logs of the Spring application](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/117d853ba2d920dd007a64076fa2f7bd) shows more details:

```
2018-03-17 17:00:24.615 ERROR 3547 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: restart transaction: HandledRetryableTxnError: TransactionRetryError: retry txn (RETRY_SERIALIZABLE): "sql txn" id=1cb57665 key=/Table/51/1/11125601/0 rw=true pri=0.04354217 iso=SERIALIZABLE stat=PENDING epo=0 ts=1521302424.604752770,1 orig=1521302424.604725980,0 max=1521302424.604725980,0 wto=false rop=false seq=3
```

There are no concurrent writes going on. All writes are strictly sequential. The problem only occurs when the concurrent reads come into play. However I think this should not cause the need to retry any transactions.
Is there something wrong with the configuration of my database connection, or what could be the issue?

Comment: Does the user running the jar have write privileges?

Comment: @MikeTung: Most writes to the database succeed. The error only occurs when `GET` requests are sent concurrently. And even then only some `PUT`s fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HandledRetryableTxnError indicates that the [transaction should be retried](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/transactions.html#transaction-retries). This occurs at `SERIALIZABLE` isolation levels when conflicts are detected between transactions.

Cockroach performs some retries automatically but not all, requiring client involvement.

You can find client-side retry examples in multiple languages on the [docs site](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-an-app-with-cockroachdb.html), including [java](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-a-java-app-with-cockroachdb.html#transaction-with-retry-logic).

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem with some magic annotations that enable client-side retrying. However I don't unterstand why this is needed at all in my case (sequential writes, concurrent reads). Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding `org.springframework.retry` as a dependency (`org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE`), importing the needed annitations

```
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable
```

and replacing

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
```

and

```
@PutMapping("/thing/")
```

with

```
@PutMapping("/thing/")
@Retryable
```

I don't understand why this is needed at all when only doing strictly sequential writes (with concurrent reads), but at least it seems to work.